# Django queryset matching null value with null OuterRef

Tags: django, orm

In Django, I'm trying to filter Foo objects by whether a Bar object exists with the same values.
The code I have below works fine for non-null values. But I also want it to return true if Foo.baz and Bar.baz are both null.

```
Foo.objects.filter(Exists(Bar.objects.filter(baz=OuterRef('baz'), qux=OuterRef('qux'))
```

I know NULL is not equal to NULL in SQL so have tried various formulations like this:

```
baz__isnull=...
```

But I'm not getting very far. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: try to look at your query in this way: print(queryset.query)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate the value of `OuterRef('baz')` and use that in your filters. Since you need to perform OR conditions you would need to use [`Q` objects [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Also it looks like filtering on the annotated `OuterRef` will not work because of this bug having [Ticket #31714](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31714), but we can get around that by using an `ExpressionWrapper` to manually specify the `output_field`. Hence if `baz` is an `IntegerField` your query would look like:

```py
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F, IntegerField, Q

q_object = Q(baz=F('outer_baz')) | (Q(baz__isnull=True) & Q(outer_baz__isnull=True))

Foo.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        Bar.objects.annotate(
            outer_baz=ExpressionWrapper(
                OuterRef('baz'),
                output_field=IntegerField()
            ) # Workaround to overcome bug
        ).filter(
            q_object,
            qux=OuterRef('qux')
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks Abdul. This seems like a great suggestion. But I am getting an error when I try it - 'ResolvedOuterRef' object has no attribute 'get_lookup'. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @peaky76 seems like you use a version of Django less than 3.0, what you described is a bug which is fixed for Django 3.0 and above but not for lower versions.

Comment: I'm on 3.1.7 so I must be doing something else wrong. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @peaky76 It seems I was mistaking your error with [Ticket #28621](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28621), your error is actually an open issue [Ticket #31714](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31714). I have described a workaround in my answer above